# Why does the java code below give StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I am getting StackOverflow error while executing the below:

```
public class StackOverflow7 {
    StackOverflow7 obj = new StackOverflow7();
    int finalCount = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
        System.out.println(i);

        StackOverflow7 localObj = new StackOverflow7();
        localObj.count(88);
        System.out.println("Final Count :: " + localObj.finalCount);
    }

    private void count(int num){
        finalCount = finalCount + num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
StackOverflow7 obj = new StackOverflow7();
```

is **always** called when you create an object of `StackOverflow7`, which you are doing in this line itself. Thus, this line recursively calls itself, until you get a StackOverflow error.

Answer (score 1):

You get the stack overflow because of this line: `StackOverflow7 obj = new StackOverflow7();`. Whenever you create a new instance, it is called and thus you create a new instance and create a new instance and so on. In your stack trace you should thus see a lot of `<clinit>` lines.

You start the whole thing by calling `StackOverflow7 localObj = new StackOverflow7();` in your main method.

To fix this either make `obj` a static field or remove it altogether, since you're not using it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line:

```
StackOverflow7 obj = new StackOverflow7();
```

Every time you create a new object this line will executet and try to create an other object